# Why do we need an empty std::lock_guard before doing condition variable notify?

Tags: c++, concurrency, mutex, condition-variable

I am currently studying Google's Filament job system. You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/master/libs/utils/src/JobSystem.cpp). The part that confuses me is this requestExit() method:

```
void JobSystem::requestExit() noexcept {
    mExitRequested.store(true);

    { std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock(mLooperLock); }
    mLooperCondition.notify_all();

    { std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock(mWaiterLock); }
    mWaiterCondition.notify_all();
}
```

I am confused why we need to lock and unlock even though there is no action in between the lock and unlock. Are there any cases where this empty lock and unlock is necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack. First, let's look at the code without that:

```
mExitRequested.store(true);
mLooperCondition.notify_all();
```

There's a possible race condition here. Some other code might have noticed that `mExitRequested` was false and started waiting for `mLooperCondition` right after we called `notify_all`.

The race would be:

1. Other thread checks `mExitRequested`, it's `false`.
2. We set `mExitRequested` to `true`.
3. We call `mLooperCondition.notify_all`.
4. Other thread waits for `mLooperCondition`.
5. Oops. Waiting for notify that already happened.

But in order to wait for a condition variable, you must hold the associated mutex. So that can only happen if some other thread held the `mLooperLock` mutex. In fact, step 4 would really be: "Other thread releases `mLooperLock` and waits for `mLooperCondition`.

So, for this race to happen, it must happen precisely like this:

1. Other thread acquires `mLooperLock`.
2. Other thread checks `mExitRequested`, it's `false`.
3. We set `mExitRequested` to `true`.
4. We call `mLooperCondition.notify_all`.
5. Other thread waits for `mLooperCondition`, releasing `mLooperLock`.
6. Oops. Waiting for notify that already happened.

So, if we change the code to:

```
mExitRequested.store(true);
{ std::lock_guard<Mutex> lock(mLooperLock); }
mLooperCondition.notify_all();
```

That ensures that no other thread could check `mExitRequested` and see `false` and then wait for `mLooperCondition`. Because the other thread would have to hold the `mLooperLock` lock through the whole process, which can't happen since we acquired it in the middle of that process.

Trying it again:

1. Other thread acquires `mLooperLock`.
2. Other thread checks `mExitRequested`, it's `false`.
3. We set `mExitRequested` to `true`.
4. By acquiring and releasing `nLooperLock`, we do not make any forward progress until the other thread releases `mLooperLock`.
5. We call `mLooperCondition.notify_all`.

Now, either the other thread blocks on the condition or it doesn't. If it doesn't, there's no problem. If it does, there's still no problem because the unlocking of `mLooperLock` is the condition variable's atomic "unlock and wait" operation, guaranteeing that it sees our notify.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Is there any reason to use atomic variable here? Why not just use regular variable and change it inside lock. Is it faster to use atomic variable in this case?

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I think I understand the reason to use atomic variable. So that we can use only one variable for both mLooperLock and mWaiterLock. We don't need to do double locking before changing mExitRequested to true.

Comment: There might be other considerations too, but I think that's the most likely explanation. One alternative would be to have two `mExitRequested` variables, one protected by each lock. Another would be to acquire both locks while changing `mExitRequested` (which I presume is a rare operation used only on shutdown). I consider the approach used in this code fragile, confusing, and hacky and would avoid it unless there were some significant disadvantages to those other approaches.